# Unable to delete file Exception WP8 Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, delete-file, isolatedstorage

I try to delete one folder with all files inside...But I got an error...I don't know why...the folder is founded with files inside too but when the code try to delete I got the issue...

```
public static bool DeleteFolder(string FolderName)
        {
            using (var iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (iso.DirectoryExists(FolderName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //get all files in the folder
                        String[] Files = iso.GetFileNames(FolderName + @"\*");
                        //delete all files
                        foreach (var file in Files)                   
                        {
                            iso.DeleteFile(Path.Combine(FolderName, file));  

                        }
                        //delete the directory
                        iso.DeleteDirectory(FolderName);
                        //return true when it's done
                        if (!iso.DirectoryExists(FolderName))
                            return true;

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        throw new MyException(MyExceptionsMessages.UnknownError + e.Message);

                    }

                }
                return true;

            }

        }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error message from the exception.

Comment: I's the title of the post .."Unable to delete file"

Comment: Are you sure your file is not locked somehow somewhere else in the app?

Comment: Well play ! I made some test and i figured out why the issue happened. I was trying to delete a picture on the phone .But before i've used a stream to bind it to a property but i had forgotten to close it so the file was still linked to the stream i guess...thanks

Comment: @PaulMartinez how did you resolve this? I am still facing the same issue. My IsolatedStorage image stream is bind to Image control. How I will release this? Please suggest, thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to dispose() the Stream u probably used before...